# How to implement a join query in django on a model with foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-models, peewee

everyone. I want to implement a "following" function on my Profile model in django. i have a relationship model and i want to join both fields so that i can select the user that maches the query.

I know peewee and i'll do something like the following:

```
def following(self):
    return ( User.select().join(Relationship, 
            on=Relationship.to_user).where(Relationship.from_user == self))
```

but i haven't been able to find how to make join queries in django.
This are the models i have on `models.py`

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    joined_at = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-joined_at']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} profile' 

    def following(self):
        """ I want to implement the query here. """

class Relationship(models.Model):
    from_user = ForeignKey(User, related_name='relationships')
    to_user = ForeignKey(User, related_name='related_to')
```

Comment: What do you want to return from the following... Please show the `sql` version of what you are asking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this;

```
def following(self):
    """ return list objects of User followings """
    return Relationship.filter(from_user=self.user)\
                       .values_list('to_user', flat=True)
```

But, I need to return it as queryset, how?

```
def following(self):
    """ this will return as `User` queryset """
    user_ids = Relationship.filter(from_user=self.user)\
                           .values_list('to_user_id', flat=True)
    return User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it worked like a charm. i was wondering and if you have time. to explain what you did and how is it that it works. or where in the docs can i learn more about that. but again, thanks.

Comment: @CésarGómez you can checkout at [QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) for more information.